# Can I have a dynamic and static website at the same time?

Tags: wordpress, hosting

The situation is the following. I’m a beginner developer. Bought a domain and a simple hosting plan (includes 1 Msql base). I created a static HTML page. I modify it sometimes to show my progress. 
Now I want to practise WordPress. Is it possible to keep this static webpage and create another dynamic page in WordPress? So this static page will be the main where I’ll put a link for the dynamic page.
Sorry if my question is too simple. I couldn’t find the answer anywhere.
Thanks!

Comment: just use your html in the root folder and in the subfolder add wordpress installation. this way you'll not need to changing `.htaccess`, rewrite some files and etc. Also, don't afraid of changing/adding files, codes. This way you'll learn faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create sub folder in public_html directory something like /public_html/xyz. so your domain will be xyz.com/xyz

now you can install wordpress in xyz folder and create dynamic website there.

Comment: Thank you! You really helped me

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a sub-domain, they are normally free inside the hosting plan. You can have a folder for the html and other folder for the WordPress. Then just assign the correct folder for the main domain to the html and the subdomain.whatever.com to the WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah there are a few ways to do it. Simplest is to name the page "index.html" and stick it in your root (public_html) directory. That page will display instead of the index.php file Wordpress uses, at least for the homepage.

Wordpress should "take over" if you navigate to any other URL.